# Transient stability of system by measuring phase shift

Tags: matlab, system, fft

I have a question regarding quantifying transient stability of a system. Without getting into the system dynamics, I'll keep my question succinct and at a conceptual level.

My system is non-linear(but I'm only interested in it's linear range of operation for the moment) and is equipped with data acquisition. I can long both the input/output of the system from the data acquisition, but I'd like to understand the effect of transient response by changing some parameters of the system.

Now, my idea is to export these signals into MATLAB, do an FFT(after appropriate windowing/filtering) and calculate the phase between the largest components of the signal. Now, if the phase calculation tells me that output is 'leading'/'lagging' the input then the system is 'unstable'/'stable' respectively correct?

The system in question is a mechanical system, where I'm applying the concepts of electrical system stability.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

So I used the tfestimate tool and got the following plot.
I used a first order butterworth filter to filter the data.

Here's the image -

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGIBm.jpg

Now, the magnitude plot doesn't cross zero and the phase plot just 'hovers' at about 0. What does this mean? 
All the bode plots I've seen in school from textbooks have a nice magnitude plot which crosses 0dB line and a phase plot that cross -180. Calculating phase/gain margin from that is easy. But how do I do it here?

Thanks!

Comment: If you can log input and output data, why don't you compute the frequency response function and that will tell you whether the system is stable or unstable. Another option is to use the System Identification Toolbox (if you have it) to create a black box or grey box model of your system. You can then examine your identified model for stability.

Comment: I used the 'tfestimate' function of matlab to estimate the Transfer function and get a phase margin. I didn't pursue it fully before I moved to this idea. Is calculation of 'phase margin' what you're referring to?
Is calculating the phase shift between the Input/Output a bad or incorrect approach? 
Thanks!!

Comment: `tfestimate` is certainly a good way to go and get the gain and phase margin. I think it's a more robust way to go about it.

Comment: Any specific source(books/authors) you recommend to refer to so that I can get started on learning system identification techniques? 
Thanks again!

Comment: Well, the Sys ID toolbox documentation is a good place to start. The toolbox is based on the work by Lennart Ljung, so any of his books should also be a good read. They're probbably referenced in the doc.